# Custom angularjs module. Communicate between directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm relatively new to Angularjs, Till now I have resolved my problems with angularjs by searching a lot on internet but I can't resolve this. Hope anyone can help me with ideas and better knowledge of angularjs.

I'm trying to make my first custom directive and I need communicate two directives in the same module through parent controller. When I try to use the require attribute I always have an error: Error: $compile:ctreq
Missing Required Controller.

Am I making something wrong?

```
(function(){

'use strict';

var INTERVAL_DELAY = 100;
var SCROLL_DELTA = 50;

angular.module('vm.hidemenu',[])

.controller('vmHideMenuTopCtrl',function(){
    return{
        sayHello : function(){
            console.log('Hello man!');
        }
    }
})

.directive('vmHideMenuTop',[function(){

    return {

        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        template: "<h1>Hello World</h1>",

        link: function(scope, element, attrs){


        },

        controller: 'vmHideMenuTopCtrl'

    }

}])

.directive('vmScrollableArea',['$window',function($window){
    return {

        restrict : "A",
        require : "^vmHideMenuTop",

        link : function(scope,element,attrs,menuCtrl){

            var e = angular.element(element[0]);
            var isScrolling = false;
            var lastScrollPos = 0;
            var scrolling; // timeout

            e.bind('scroll',function(event){

                var obj = event.target;
                var scrollTop = obj.scrollTop;

                isScrolling = true;

                $window.clearTimeout(scrolling);

                if(scrollTop > lastScrollPos ){
                    console.log('scroll Down');
                }else{
                    console.log('scroll UP');
                }

                scrolling = $window.setTimeout(function(){
                    isScrolling = false;
                    lastScrollPos = obj.scrollTop;
                    menuCtrl.sayHello();
                },INTERVAL_DELAY);


            })

        }

    }
}]);

}());
```

I've tried other ways to achieve this, like firing events and try to hear those events. Thats only works if I fire the events through $rootScope. I read that this is a bad practice so i don't know how to achieve this.

The idea behind the code is to have an scrollable area that can communicate with the top navbar to hiding or showing it, just like mobile apps do.

Sorry if I can't express myself in the best way, I'm not english native.

Thanks for your consideration and help!

Comment: Can you create a plunkr? Is the vmScrollableArea inside vmHideMenuTop?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use a separate controller for each directive and a service to share the data. You could use an observer pattern like so:

```
app.service('myService', function () {
    this.data = [];
    var observers = [];
    var self = this;

    this.addObserver = function (callback) {
        observers.push(callback);
    };

    var notifyObservers = function () {
        angular.forEach(observers, function (callback) {
            callback(self.data);
        });
    };


    this.addData = function (data) {
        this.data.push(data);
        notifyObservers();

    }
});
```

and inside the controllers:

```
myService.registerObserverCallback(function (data) {
            $scope.myData = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Or if you just wanted to use events with the `$broadcast` inside the service when data is updated and inside a controller use `$on` to request the updated data.